# Is it safe to leave/exit the stored procedure without commit or rollback on a transaction?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transaction

Like the code below is it safe to do that?

```sql
create definer=`root`@`%` procedure `test`()
label: begin

declare exit handler for sqlexception rollback;
start transaction;

select condition from table where id = someid for update;

if condition = false then
  leave label;
end if;

// some query;
commit;
end$$
```

Comment: Implicit actions cannot be safe. Add rollback before leave.

Comment: In your example, the `FOR UPDATE` will continue to lock something until the next `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that transaction control does *not* belong to stored procedures at all, apart from some very particular circumstances (e.g. where you want to log audit records regardless of what happens to the "outer" transaction -- i.e. "autonomous transaction"). The procedure has no way of knowing if it is part of a larger unit of work and therefore, if it commits or rolls back, it might violate consistency rules of a larger transaction.

Commit or roll back at the level where business rules are implemented.

In other words, yes, in the majority of cases it's the right thing to do "to leave/exit the stored procedure without commit or rollback" and let the caller decide (provided that you don't hide the exception if it occurs).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the comment of my question, the answer is "NO", especially the `FOR UPDATE` it will hold the lock until a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` is called.